# how to triger some func when session destroy by closing browser in JS?

Tags: javascript, session, tracking

I am trying to catch moment when browser is closed by visitor. With window.beforeunload it works perfect for pc users with needed browsers for me. However, I am detecting mobile users with  "visibilitychange". It works in some browsers but in safari and chrome with some mobile devices cannot catch when browser closes.
After research I couldnt find any way except session. Although I am not sure if this is solution. Is there any way to trigger function when session ends by closing browser ?
Or is there better way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

An almost cross-working example with `beforeunload`:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  var confirmationMessage = "\o/";

  (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
  return confirmationMessage;                            //Webkit, Safari, Chrome
});
```

more details on : [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/beforeunload?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/beforeunload)